# SmartSheet API - Delete rows from a specific index

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am working on integration data from another system to Smartsheet via API. The result I'd like to achieve is that each time run API a sheet, data would be deleted from the 4th index row. Afterward, new data will be added.

I wonder if there is any easy way to implement the deletion from a specific index row.
I 've tried the following function in node JS

```
function resetSheet (sheetid) {
  // Get sheet
  smartsheet.sheets.getSheet({sheetid})
    .then(function(sheetInfo) {
      const rowIdList = sheetInfo.rows.map(item => item.id);
      return rowIdList;
    })
    .then(data => {
      const deleteIds = data.splice(3);
      deleteIds.forEach(rowId => {
        smartsheet.sheets.deleteRow({
          sheetId: sheetId,
          rowId: rowId
        })
          .then(function(results) {
            console.log(results);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      })
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

It works but sometimes the Nodejs alert me with the following error and there are some rows that are not deleted

```
errorCode=4004, message=Request failed because sheetId XXX is currently being updated by another request that uses the same access token.  Please retry your request once the previous request has completed., refId=16hz2dgyh47v0
```

Do i miss anything on the above code?
Hopefully we can have a better solution in this case. Solution with another language (example for C#) would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Smartsheet as any cloud based system takes some time to update the requests, if you are doing the updates/deletions in rapid fire, there is a chance that the previous request has not been completed by when you are sending the new one.

You can add a simple delay with a simple sleep to check if that is the reason, or implement an incremental retry function (that works for me).

Also if you run other script using the same key, and the other script runs at the same time on the same sheet, you will get that error too (it used to happen to me when I did updates and backups at the same time on the same sheet), you can avoid that by using two different keys (users) for simultaneous tasks, or divide the tasks at different times.

Comment: Thank you so much for this useful suggestion. 
In addition of that, do you have any easier idea to implement the deletion of rows from a specific index instead of looping for one by one row id in Smartsheet? Any idea on C#?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Alex Argumedo wrote, it might be a rapid-fire-issue.

To solve this rapid-fire-issue here, you may use the following approach:

- generate an empty variable storing a string.
- add all the rowIds, that need to be deleted to this string, ... allways separated by "," ("Comma") You may reuse your "forEach"-Loop for this.
- After the generation of this long string, do the deletion of all the rows in one single API-Call by using this long string.

As stated in the "Smartsheet - Official API and SDK Documentation" the string should  contain all the rowsIds of the rows, which need to be deleted:
[Smartsheet - Official API and SDK Documentation](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/rows#operation/delete-rows)